# events for picturebox in standard windows mobile 6

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

I am new in windows mobile development.How to redirect to another page.when i click on picture box in standard  windows mobile 6.
There is no click event for standard  windows mobile 6.it's is not a touch screen mobile.
could any one help me ?

Added-If main screen 9 icon/picturebox.then how to go from one icon to another.any event for that.if have any link or any code.please give me?

thx in advance...
Regards
pankaj

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows Mobile Standard doesn't have a touch screen, so there is no way you can 'click' on a picture.

You will need to use something else to navigate between pages (forms?).  With the standard controls you'll need to use either a LinkLabel or menu item to do your navigatino.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to hook up your form's key press event handlers and handle the left/right/up/down key press events manually.

Your custom logic would then be responsible for displaying the change in focus somehow (perhaps a border around the active picture box etc).

A "click" could then be replaced with a press of the action (center d-pad) button.